# android maps :  array index out of bound exception

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I have a task to show 458 markers to show in Android maps. And to avoid performance related issues I update the data on map using an `AsyncTask` instance.

Here is a short scenario of what I do.

1. I fetch the latitude/longitude of 458 locations around UK.
2. I run the loop and as per Android Blog tutorial I add them in `ItemizedOverlay` class
3. After every 50th iteration I call `publishProgress` method to place 50 markers in map.

After the 50th iteration the flow goes into `onProgressUpdate` via `publishProgress` and here is my code of `onProgressUpdate` method

```
// MapOverLays = mapView.getOverlays(); 
//This line was called in asyc task's constructor   
// Hello Overlay is an instance of ItemizedOverlay.
mapOverlays.add(helloOverLay);
//MapView.getController - Also called in Constructor
controller.setZoom(12);

controller.animateTo(centerPoint);
controller.setCenter(centerPoint);
```

This code throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` and the logcat doesn't show any of the class from my module. Here is the logcat dump if it elaborates my problem.

```
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getIndexToDraw(ItemizedOverlay.java:211)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.draw(ItemizedOverlay.java:240)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:476)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-07 11:34:48.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(508):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

P.S. I have tested the application with relatively smaller (10) and relatively larger (150) iterations instead of 50. But the application throws same Error.

Comment: I have temporarily get the solution. Instead of adding pins frequently i first prepare whole data and than add it in map using `onPostExecute()` as described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870743 but it still doesn't meet my requirement to save the time to load all pins. However i can get rid of that exception. But waiting for any suggestions that improve the loading time.... Thanks anyway... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have temporarily get the solution. Instead of adding pins frequently i first prepare whole data and than add it in map using onPostExecute() as described [Android 2.1 GoogleMaps ItemizedOverlay ConcurrentModificationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870743) but it still doesn't meet my requirement to save the time to load all pins. However i can get rid of that exception. But waiting for any suggestions that improve the loading time.... Thanks anyway... :-)

Comment: I have the same problem with my mapview.  I have yet to dive deep into the problem.  Have you tried the answer above dealing with calling populate?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Looks like it was caused by updating the data in the ItemizedOverlay without calling `populate` afterwards.

```
public class ListOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
...
  public synchronized void updateLocations(List<OverlayItem> newLocations) {
    locations.clear();
    locations.addAll(newLocations);
    populate(); // this was missing
  }
  protected synchronized OverlayItem createItem(int index) {
    return locations.get(index);
  }
  public synchronized int size() {
    return locations.size();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
populate();

Not "always" work !!!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, only I get a slightly different stacktrace.  I found the solution is to do the following to your itemizedOverlay object after you add your overlays:

```
setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
populate();
```

I can't take credit for this, I found the answer [here](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/android-itemizedoverlay-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-nullpointerexception-workarounds/).  I don't know why you have to do this, but it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call mapView's invalidate() in UI thread after new pin items are added to the overlay each time.