# ConcurrentModificationException in MapActivity

Tags: android, android-mapview, concurrentmodification, mapactivity

this is my first question here, so if anything's wrong, do tell.

Now, I have a `public class MainMap extends MapActivity` which uses a `MyLocationListener` for the user's location and a [HelloItemizedOverlay](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).
I'm getting certain POI's from an XML-file which I want to add markers (pretty basic Overlays).

User presses a button, AsyncTask starts:

```
private class GetPOITask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

 protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    clearMapOverlay();
    if(!isBusyAddingOverlays)
    {
       connect(params[0]);
    }
    return null;
 }

 protected void onPreExecute() {
  clearMapOverlay();
 }
}
```

Clearing out the MapOverlay (this.mv is a MapView):

```
public void clearMapOverlay()
 {
  this.mv.getOverlays().remove(placesItemizedOverlay);
  this.mv.postInvalidate();
  this.mv.getOverlays().add(myLoc);
 }
```

This is the method that my connect-method calls when I have enough information to add a marker:

```
private void addOverlayToList(int id, GeoPoint point, String title, String description)
{
 //Log.e("Debug", "Adding overlay");
 placesItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new POIOverlay(id, point, title, description));
 this.mv.getOverlays().add(placesItemizedOverlay);
}
```

That should be all the relevant code.

The problem is that when I add the POI's *and* zoom the map (or move it), I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

I've searched through this site, reading similar threads ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870743/android-2-1-googlemaps-itemizedoverlay-concurrentmodificationexception) for example) but I can't really find what I'm doing wrong.

Knowing myself, it's probably something obvious.

Thanks in advance,

iarwain

Answer (score 0):

This could come from the fact that `addOverlayToList()` is called from `connect()` which is called in a different Thread (`doInBackground()`). Only the thread wich initiated the UI can touch its views.

Move the add overlay calls into `onPostExecute()` (which you should override) of `GetPOITask`.